# Hide all other divs with the same name on div hover, show hovered div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I have a list of PHP generated coupons, all with the div id (#coupon) and the class of (.coupon_hover)

When the user hovers over one of the divs named #coupon then I want all of the other divs named #coupon to disappear except for the one which is being hovered over. I would preferably like to do this in CSS only.

I have been able to get all the coupons to hide below the one which is hovered using this code :

```
#coupon:hover ~ .coupon_hover {
display:none;
}
```

I have made a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/04t5psbu/2/

See how when you hover over the second coupon the first one stays and the last one hides, I want it so that when any of them hover then all the others hide accept for the one hovered over, the name of the div must keep its name as just (#coupon) it cannot be #coupon1 #coupon2 ect....

Thank you for any help

Comment: IDs should be unique

Comment: Not when just being styled ? like a coupon

Comment: It has always to be uniqe. No exceptions.

Comment: then you have bugs like this. JS and CSS are excepting that one ID is used max once.

Comment: The coupons are identical though, I want them styled the same. Why would i have 500 divs all with different ID's and the same CSS page 500 times

Comment: Whats the deal? Use classes then, not IDs!

Comment: This is what a class is used for...

Comment: Okay then, On the coupon wrapper i can remove the ID #coupon and just use the class (.coupon) can i still achieve what im looking for ?

Comment: If you still want to go with the IDs, then on hover add class and on all others add different class which will display:none, visibility: hidden; Use `.toggleClass`.

Comment: I can achieve hiding all of the coupons after the current hovered now i have changed the duplicated ID's to Classes using : .coupon:hover ~ .coupon however i need all to hide except the current hovered

Comment: I have told you what to do, that is the quickest "hack". On the more important side, never use ids as classes.

Comment: @super11 I dont know which one the user has hovered over, they could hover over any

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/04t5psbu/6/)

**Note:**

- You should have unique ids. So to manipulate similar elements use class.
- You should use `visibility: hidden` instead of `display: none`. `display: none` will change DOM structure making your focused element to shift and eventually triggering focus out.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, This is exactly what i was after.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this.

> Hiding an element can be done by setting the display property to none. The element will be hidden, and the page will be displayed as if the element is not there. visibility:hidden; also hides an element.
>   However, the element will still take up the same space as before.

```js
$(".coupon").on("mouseover",function(){
  $(".coupon").not(this).css("visibility","hidden");
});
$(".coupon").on("mouseout",function(){
  $(".coupon").css("visibility","visible");
});
```

```css
.coupon{
  width:100px;
  height:70px;
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="coupon">
  Coupon 1
</div>
<div class="coupon">
  Coupon 2
</div>
<div class="coupon">
  Coupon 3
</div>
<div class="coupon">
  Coupon 4
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, This is exactly what i was after.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it in css may be this can help you.

```
<div id="coupon-container">
  <div id="coupon1" class="custom-size">
     One
  </div>
  <div id="coupon2" class="custom-size">
     Two
  </div>
  <div id="coupon3" class="custom-size">
     Three
  </div>
  <div id="coupon4" class="custom-size">
     Four
  </div>  
</div>
```

Css:

```
 .custom-size{
    height:150px;
    width:600px;  
    border: 1px solid red;
 }

 #coupon-container:hover   div[id^='coupon']:not(:hover) {
     display: none;  
 }
```

Well the same thing can be done in javascipts by finding the ids of other element and hiding them.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery for that and hide all other coupons when user exploring the one with help of mouse event.

```
    $(function() {

   // on mouse enter hide other and show current one
   $(".coupon_hover1").mouseenter(function(event) {
     $(".coupon_hover1").each(function() {
       $(this).hide();
     });
     $(this).show();
   });

   // on mouse leave show all coupons as before
   $(".coupon_hover1").mouseleave(function(event) {
     $(".coupon_hover1").each(function() {
       $(this).show();
     });
   });
 })
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/04t5psbu/7/)